# What is the point of having a Q&A website dedicated to coffee?

Tags: coffee-culture

I wonder what could be the reason for stack exchange to host a website for a simple day to day task that looks so trivial. Is coffee making that hard?

Comment: There's a lot to know and discuss about coffee, especially when you get into specialty coffee. Unfortunately most of the questions here are just about people cleaning their moka pots.

Comment: Please post questions about an SE site on the corresponding Meta site, but please note that as it’s written, your post is very much opinion-based.

Comment: If you wonder, I suggest you look at a few sample questions, from [very basic](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/using-nescafe-gold-on-espresso-maker) to [quite complex](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/can-i-brew-espresso-with-14g-portafilter-basket). Some users start at basically no knowledge and need a helping hand, others are fine tuning their skills with feedback from the community. We welcome all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone is new to the world of coffee, (*it is not a day to day task for them and there are hundred of ways to make coffee from all over the world*) and they  have a question about coffee. They do not know anybody who is knowledgeable about the subject.

They turn to the interwebs to find information. They do  a web search but there is so much crap and misinformation to filter out that a good and correct  answer is very difficult to find, so they think Gosh why don't i put up a site were  anybody can ask a question about coffee and those in the know can post answers to those questions.

The best answers will be voted on so they rise to the top and eventually a correct answer will be chosen. Misinformation will be called out and not allowed to misguide.

In the future if somebody else may have the same question and they do an interweb search on it, one of the search hits will be the [Question and Answer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/)  site where a correct answer was given to the very question they are wanting an answer for.

Perhaps this could work for [All kinds of things](https://stackexchange.com/sites#)

Even for questions with seemingly obvious answers like "*What is the point of having a Q&A website*"

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that this is a bad question. If fact, I believe it is an opportunity to educate and inform someone on the culture and art behind making coffee. There are many different types of coffee and there are plenty of ways in which coffee is made. For example, you can generally tell the quality of the coffee bought in packs based on the seal if you let too much air touch your coffee grounds then you will lose some of the flavors that make a good coffee. Then there is the type of coffee bean used and method of roasting which can help deliver the taste you want. This is very similar to how you program a computer changing certain variables leads to a different output. Then there is how the bean is processed to make the grounds used in your coffee. I am a firm believer that you will greatly improve the taste of your coffee if you grind the beans yourself but others have different methods. Lastly, there is how is the coffee made? There are different cultures around the globe and all of them have different methods for brewing coffee. This also affects the resulting cup of coffee. I encourage you to look into different methods of producing coffee and feel free to ask questions. That is the purpose of this forum. We all here have different lives but we all drink coffee and there are pride and joy that comes with taking a little extra time to produce something you enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the coffee, yes

You don't have to learn something in orders to make instant coffee, but try making coffee with v60, soon enough you will understand how changing a degree in water temperature or adding 2 more grams coffee can make a whole difference.

Being a barista is not a simple task.